# Jboss data source or properties from classpath resource

Tags: jboss, jboss-eap-6

Is it possible in Jboss eap-6.4 to configure the datasource using a resource loaded from the classpath?

I would like it to be a classpath resource because I have a mechanism that securely substitutes properties in files loaded as classpath resources.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to load JDBC driver from class-path ? which resources you are trying to load from class-path ? If you are trying to load JDBC driver from class-path then you can add JDBC driver jar in 'deployment' directory in standalone mode.

Comment: Not trying to load JDBC driver, but configuration such as username, password, and connection URL.

Comment: You can create properties file while contains name and value pair. For property substitution you have to use expression like as '${DB.User.Name}' 
 '<security>
          <user-name>${DB.User.Name}</user-name>
          <password>${DB.Password}</password>
 </security>'
Pass properties file while starting server instance, using "-P=/path/to/properties" file.